# How to reach a host in the same network by hostname?

Tags: server, networking, dns, avahi, hostname

I have a network which connects a couple of hosts.
I would like to be able to reach other hosts from one of them using the hostname.
I just discovered the ".local" domain, which is available through `avahi` and `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.
But it's not set up this way on my servers.
And I don't want to create an entry in my dns server.
Is there an other way to do so ?

Comment: Avahi mDNS is pretty good for you needs. See answer about `/etc/nsswitch.conf` for how to configure it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your /etc/nsswitch.conf should already have this for mDNS (avahi):

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4
```

Just install `avahi-daemon` on the machines you want talking to eachother, and you should be set to use HOSTNAME.local like this:

```
ssh yourmachine.local
```

Comment: This is the answer I wish I could upvote twice.

Comment: If the issue still persists, check the status of avahi-daemon using `systemctl status avahi-daemon`. If its diabled/inactive, run `systemctl enable avahi-daemon` and `systemctl start avahi-daemon`.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to add an entry in your `/etc/hosts` file:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/hosts
```

An entry takes the form `123.123.123.123 host.domain` or just `123.123.123.123 host`.

If you do that, you can now for example `ssh host` and it will connect to `123.123.123.123`

Comment: Sorry, i forget to mention that i doesn't want to do so for two reason.
First for secuity reasons, these machines a server. And i think, it could be an issue.
Secondly, i know that my hosts will changes there ip adresse soon. And i don't want to update this conf every time.

edit: a third reason, i use dhcp, so the network manager will generate a new one frequently. But i know there is a trick to do let it do it.

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution.
Using the file, `/etc/dhccp3/dhcient.conf`
There is a line starting like this, `send host-name`
This could be modified to
send host-name 'server1'

This solution look nice, but i don't know if the every machine which use the same dns will see my "server1" hostname.

Another bad side to this solution, i need to specify the hostname here and in the `/etc/hosts`

I just know that this file (`/etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf`) is not a script, so i can't use a environnement variable to fill this line correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can let dynamic DHCP add the entry in DNS, instead of yourself.

Comment: But i don't want them to be expose to the whole internet.Just to find them in my localnetwork

Answer (score 0):

if using avahi-daemon, you may need to copy ssh.services into /etc/avahi/services. On mine,

`sudo cp /usr/share/doc/avahi-daemon/examples/ssh.service /etc/avahi/services/`