# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server hostname connection by Putty from Windows 11 not detected

Tags: networking, server, ssh, dns, dhcp

I try to figure out why I cannot connect using Putty from Windows 11 to **Ubuntu Server 22.04** (fresh install) by hostname but for **Ubuntu desktop 22.04**(fresh install) without problem. Both system are run on VM with same settings and same virtual adapter. I connect using IP but this is temporary solution.

I check also ping from Windows 11. Ping working for hostname of **Ubuntu desktop** but not for **Ubuntu server**

> Ping request could not find host ***hostname*** . Please check the name and try again.

Which component shall I install to have Ubuntu Server hostname brodcast like in desktop version?

Comment: That's possibly because the `avahi-daemon` package is installed on the Desktop, but not on the Server - see for example [Cannot ssh into Ubuntu Server by hostname](https://askubuntu.com/a/144288/178692)

Comment: @steeldriver Great thanks install **avahi-daemon** resolved my issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to be install **avahi-daemon** package It is not present in Ubuntu Server:

Install:

```
sudo apt install avahi-daemon
```

Check if its working:

```
sudo systemctl status avahi-daemo
```