# Cannot ping Ubuntu server by host name

Tags: networking, ssh, ping, hostname

I just installed Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS onto my NUC. The installation went well, but from my MacBook Air, I cannot ping the server by name (hostname is "nuc"):

```
ping -c3 nuc
ping -c3 nuc.local
```

Both results in the message "ping: cannot resolve nuc: Unknown host", but the first command failed much quicker. I have a raspberry pi running Raspbian 10 with hostname rasperrypi and I was able to `ping -c3 raspberrypi.local` just fine.

My router is a Nighthawk RX5800 and the internal private IP addresses are 192.168.1.X.

As the result of this problem, I could not `ssh nuc.local`, but has to do IP address: `ssh 192.168.1.16`. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Probably related: [Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server hostname connection by Putty from Windows 11 not detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1422448/ubuntu-22-04-lts-server-hostname-connection-by-putty-from-windows-11-not-detecte)

Comment: @steeldriver That is just what the doctor ordered. Thank you.