# Can SSH with IP but not host name?

Tags: server, ssh, lan, openssh

When I SSH directly to the server's IP address, it works. (ssh michael@10.1.10.129) For reference, here is the resulting prompt:

```
michael@noranetserver:~$
```

However ssh-ing by name doesn't work like so:

```
ssh michael@noranetserver
ssh: Could not resolve hostname noranetserver: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Why would this be?

Comment: You could try nslookup and see if the 'noranetserver' is in the names list. `nslookup noranetserver` if it is not that may be the reason.

Comment: Is nslookup preinstalled on most UNIX-likes? Or must I download it?

Comment: Yes it should be in by default

Comment: It returned ** server can't find noranetserver: NXDOMAIN
Does that mean anything?

Comment: Sucky think about SSH: Using NAT (especially on port overload), and DHCP make it hard to SSH because of the constant changed, vs a home network where you can set stuff up how you want. :/ hope that answer below helped.

Answer (score 10):

You could try adding `10.1.10.129   noranetserver` to /etc/hosts, to make the computer you connect from aware of the server hostname.

There are other ways as well, as pointed out in the following questions: [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144280/cannot-ssh-into-ubuntu-server-by-hostname) and [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23741/how-to-reach-a-host-in-the-same-network-by-hostname).

Comment: Is there a more universal way to do this? I was hoping to using the computer's hostname for a variety of other things on the network. I can't hold on to the static IP indefinitely, I just convinced my superior to let me use one as a stopgap measure.

Comment: Sure, there are other ways to make the server advertise its hostname. Please refer to the following questions: [1](http://askubuntu.com/questions/144280/cannot-ssh-into-ubuntu-server-by-hostname) and [2](http://askubuntu.com/questions/23741/how-to-reach-a-host-in-the-same-network-by-hostname).

Answer (score 0):

Try [avahi-daemon](https://linux.die.net/man/8/avahi-daemon) package, it just work as a service.