# ssh: connect to host port 22: Connection timed out when hostname used

Tags: networking, ssh

I have two Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.x installs at home and trying to ssh between them, I can connect by Internal IP but not by hostname
Setup:

Machine A: 192.x.x.115

Machine B: 192.x.x.125

both installs have ssh running and I can connect fine using internal IP.

From Machine B I would like to connect to Machine A using hostname  or hostname.ddns.net

Here are things I have setup:

**Machine A:**

machineA> /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1    machineA.ddns.net machineA

192.x.x.115  machineA
```

machineA> /etc/hostname

```
machineA.ddns.net
```

machineA> /etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search hsd1.xx.isp.net
```

**Machine B:**

machineB> `ssh user@192.x.x.115`  # i.e machineA is successful

machineB> ssh -vvv user@machineA.ddns.net
gives

```
Connecting to machineA.ddns.net [ISP assigned address] port 22.

ssh: connect to host machineA.ddns.net port 22: Connection timed out
```

machineB> ssh -vvv user@machineA

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname machineA: Name or service not known
```

SSH_from_external_to_machineA is successful

ssh user@machineA.ddns.net  # is successful

commands tried on machineA:

machineA> `sudo service ssh status   # gives active(running)`

machineA> `sudo netstat -alnp | grep :22  # shows :22 with LISTEN`

machineA> `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -j ACCEPT`

1. I feel ISP is not blocking ssh from ssh since I can connect from external using machineA.ddns.net
2. Router is allowing port 22 since I can connect using IP.

I feel hostname is not resolved correctly, please review and let me know if I am missing any additional steps.

Thanks,

Additional edits:

`machineB> ping machineA_Hostname`   is successful

`machineB> nslookup machineA.ddns.net` is showing external IP as expected

`machineB> ssh machineA`   # Could not resolve hostname: Name or service not known

`machineB> ssh machineA.ddns.net`
attempts to connect to exact external IP that was reported by ping and 'Connection timed out'

Comment: How is machineB to know what IP address machineA is located at? The `/etc/hosts` file on both machines will need entries that point to each other if you are not specifically setting `A` record DNS entries anywhere.

Comment: @user68186: thanks for link, I checked  some commands. My issue is ssh from machineB does not recognize the hostname of machineA.  However ping works with both internal IP and hostname which makes it feel like it is hostname related.

Comment: @Matigo: I use 'ipconfig' on both machines and know their internal IPs.  I have edited machineA /etc/hosts and put in internal IP like     192.x.x.115   machineA.ddns.net   machineA                  machineB can ssh to machineA using IP address, it just does not know hostname.       machineB can also ping using hostname,     Hope I clarified. can you please elaborate on the required DNS entries.    Thanks

Comment: ssh: Could not resolve hostname machineA.local: Name or service not known

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid hardcoding the internal IP address, setup avahi-daemon on Ubuntu for so you can reach hostname `ubuntu.local` from host OS.

`sudo apt-get install avahi-daemon avahi-discover avahi-utils libnss-mdns mdns-scan`

Comment: Thank you, this solution worked and I could ssh ubuntu.local successfully. While searching on forums I found https://askubuntu.com/questions/23741/how-to-reach-a-host-in-the-same-network-by-hostname  which may help future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

You wanna ssh **machine_B** from **machine_A** via **hostname**, right?

so just put the internal IP of machine_B with a desired name (for calling machine_B) in machine_A

in order to do that, just edit /etc/hosts of machine_A and add something like below:

```
192.168.222.1 my_lovely_machine_B
```

now if you type:

```
ssh user@my_lovely_machine_B
```

that should work!

**BUT** if you don't want to bother yourself for hardcoding the internal IP address and make changes everytime (Because IP addresses may change) you can do two things.

First approach: The hard approach but the practical one: you need to run a DNS service such as BIND to get what you want

Second approach: The simple one but not good for every scenario (For you is OK): write a bash script for automation of setting static IP for machine_B and let it run on every startup. in this way you don't need to worry about IP changes and always your machine_B has the same IP.

Comment: This worked, Is it possible to avoid hardcoding the internal IP address, since the IP could change in future.  If possible I would like to machineB to be recognized by all internal machines without hardcoding IP in every client.

Comment: Of course is possible ! . I edit the answer for that as well